# I think I made a mistake with this tkinter widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, graphical-interaction

So till now I want to make a simple button but it gives me an error screen, what am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

tk = tk.Tk()
tk.geometry()
tk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(tk, text = "Exit", height = 2, width = 2, command = tk.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)





tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This `tk = tk.Tk()` shadows `tk` the module with the `Tk` object, and creates a whole lot of problems. Rename it to something else and it should work.

Comment: When asking questions about errors, please include the full error in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing `tk` with something else:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", height=2, width=2, command=root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)


tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `tk = tk.Tk()`, because you are also referring to `tkinter` as `tk`. So either:

Change your imports(not recommended):

```
import tkinter as _tk

tk = _tk.Tk() # And so on..
```

or change your variable name(recommended):

```
root = tk.Tk() # And change tk.geometry to root.geometry() and so on
```